# Use a timer to move blocks in Tetris like game

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm just getting into using Swift and trying to make a tetris-like game for practice.

I have a timer that every 10 seconds, generates a new 'box' or shape and then moves them down.
`var TimeMethod = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: Selector("doMethod"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

And this calls the following function `doMethod` which calls `MoveBlocks`

```
func doMethod(){
    if(true){
        if(number_of_blocks != 1){
            current_min = current_max + 1
        }
        var box_d = createBox(self.size.width/2, yinit: self.size.height/2)
        makeBox(box_d)
        var Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("MoveBlocks"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        number_of_blocks++
    }
}

func MoveBlocks(){
    var Sprite = childNodeWithName("BOX_"+String(current_min))
    var y_min = Sprite?.position.y

    for i in current_min...current_max{
        var Sprite_self = childNodeWithName("BOX_"+String(i))
        if(Sprite_self?.position.y < y_min){
            y_min = (Sprite?.position.y)!
        }
    }

    if(y_min > CGFloat(BOX_WIDTH/2)){
        for i in current_min...current_max {
            var sprite_self = childNodeWithName("BOX_"+String(i))
            //var current_pos = sprite_self?.position.y
            sprite_self?.position.y = (sprite_self?.position.y)! - CGFloat(BOX_WIDTH)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I call this, it seems to work for the first shape, it seems to move each block down by the `BOX_WIDTH/2`. The next shape is moved down by `BOX_WIDTH` and the third is `3/2*BOX_WIDTH` and I'm not too sure why its doing it and would hope that someone could help me please.

Comment: Any bit of advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but you should pay attention on few things : 1) Naming conventions... It should be variableName, ClassName. 2) Use SKActions instead of NSTimer in SpriteKit (search SO about why). 3) if(true) doesn't make sense, and you can remove it. 4) Don't use force unwrapping like that if you are not completely sure that underlying value is not nil.

Comment: Or you may use forced unwrapping if you want to trigger the crash which will indicate that is something really wrong in a game (this is usually done during development phase).

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips. Coming back to when you said use SKactions instead of NSTimer, doesnt the action just do the actual movement. If I want it happen every second but the movement only takes half a second, then wont I need the timer so i can call the action each second?

Comment: I've added an action in instead of the `sprite_self?.position.y = (sprite_self?.position.y)! - CGFloat(BOX_WIDTH)
        }` bit. But it appears to be doing the MoveBlocks function one more time each time its called in the timer. It does it once on the first, twice on the second, etc.

Comment: Nope. SKAction class has a lot of methods for time related actions. You can repeat certain action after time delay by repeating the action sequence. In it simplest form, that would be SKAction.waitForDuration() + some other action, repeated using methods like SKAction.repeatActionForever()... NSTimer is not affected by scene's or view's paused state. SKActions are paused automatically if you pause the scene or a view.

Comment: there is a lot of things wrong with this code, the biggest culprit  is NSTimer like @WhirlWind has mentioned.  Every 10 seconds, you spawn a new timer. so 0 seconds in, 0 timers calling MoveBlocks, 10 seconds in, 1 timer, 20 seconds in, 2 timers ...  This is why the blocks are moving differently,  every 10 seconds ADDS another MoveBlock count

Comment: Yeah I get that now. I'll give it a go and see how I get on. I'm very new to swift :D Thanks!